# golang cron job，How to start job from the past time? or How to set a specific past time as original cron start time?

Tags: go, cron

I want to execute function using this crontab library https://github.com/robfig/cron

```
       parser := cron.NewParser(
        cron.Second | cron.Minute | cron.Hour | cron.Dom | cron.Month | cron.Dow | cron.Descriptor,
    )
    c := cron.New(cron.WithParser(parser))

    // 0 0 */5 * *
    c.AddFunc("0 0 0 */5 * ?", func() {
        fmt.Println("Every 5 day")
    })
```

If this program run on 2024-01-01,then  `fmt.Println("Every 5 day")`  will run on 2024-01-06、2024-01-11 ......，
but if I restart this program on  2024-01-02,then  `fmt.Println("Every 5 day")`  will run on 2024-01-07、2024-01-12 .......,

So ,How to avoid restart influence？or How to start job from the past time?  or How to set a specific past time as original cron start time ?

Comment: That's simply not how cron works. You _either_ define an interval (like "every 5 days") and all it will run every 5 days but at any day, _or_ you define at which days of the week ("always Saturday") _or_ day of month ("on the 3rd, 12th and 28th") it will run.

Comment: "every 5 days" will run on different dates from first time program start if you restart it ,so how to avoid it ?

Comment: "so how to avoid it" you simply cannot if you want to use cron. This is a XY problem and you have to redesign.